# How to use dlls from another folder in windows

Tags: windows, dll, windows-10, windows-server-2012, dll-search-path

We have some set of open source applications in common folder which shares the common libraries(dlls) from the same location. We are using windows 10 and 2012 server.

Recently we have updated the some of applications and that are not compatible with old dlls. So we upgraded the dlls, but the other applications not compatible with the upgraded dlls. We don't want to move the applications into separate folders.

Can we do some settings(like Dynamic-Link Library Redirection) to make the specific application to use the libraries from different location. We tried to create the folder with application_name.exe.local(say myapp.exe.local) and copied the files into that folder based on the below suggestion but not working.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection

Comment: You may set different PATH environment variables for each application.

Comment: If the two versions of the dll are in the same folder, they must have a different name each. So what's wrong with loading the correct one for each binary ? I'm sorry, i probably get you wrong but that's... incomplete to me.